# Trying to login into the Firebase CLI with Google account returns 'Something went wrong'

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I have installed Firebase CLI globally on my computer with `npm install -g firebase-tools` and confirmed by typing `firebase` into the Command Prompt. When I try to login with the command `firebase login`, I am immediately redirected to a page where I can choose a Google account with which I can login to. I agree to Firebase CLI accessing my account and immediately get a page saying [*'Something went wrong - Sorry, something went wrong there. Please try again.'*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ew8Yx.png)

I have attempted launching Command Prompt in administrator mode as well as `firebase login --no-localhost`, with the same results. Pressing *Next* only returns me the same page in my Google account language and, eventually, returns me to my Google Account page.

I am not sure why this is happening since there is no error code: What should I do?

Comment: It would help to include the version of firebase tools you are using (`firebase --version`) and even perhaps your node version (`node --version`). Additionally, you can see debugging info on most firebase commands by adding the `--debug` flag. Not sure what that returns for the login function, but maybe something useful (just be sure not to post anything sensitive).

Comment: I've had the same issue 1 month ago and now it appeared again.

Comment: Hey @Dimitrije, are opening the link on Google Chrome? That's what solved it for me. I was opening it on Brave. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73561808/4756173).

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro Actually the funny thing is that I'm using Firefox, and trying it on... Brave.. fixed the issue (I don't have Chrome on my computer so I tried this before downloading it). Maybe something about some ad-block extension that made it act that way? Absolutely weird interaction I am not sure what to make of this