# Getting "Somthing went wrong" when trying to login my CLI into Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I'm coming back into using Firebase after about 2 years, and now I'm having trouble trying to login my CLI into Firebase (yes, I have installed `npm i -g firebase-tools`). I've tried 3 different commands for it, all of them result in one of the images below:

- `firebase login`
- `firebase login:ci`
- `firebase login:ci --no-localhost`

Here is the result, after I allow Firebase CLI to integrate with my account:

[image: Something went wrong 1]

[image: Something went wrong 2]

I had already tried this 1 month ago on a Windows machine, but now I'm getting it again on my ArchLinux. Does anyone even have a clue about what's going on? I *am* logged in successfully on the browser, so I guess it's a problem on Google's end, with an incredibly generic error message.

> Just found out someone else has had the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73546284/4756173) yesterday.

> I've also [registered this as a bug](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4936) on the respective repo on Github.

And here is what appears on my Inspector's Console, 2 improvement issues:

[image: Improvement Issues]

Comment: Open the browser debugger. Are there any additional error messages that might indicate the source of the problem?

Comment: All I see are 2 improvement issues: `Audit usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform`; and `Page layout may be unexpected due to Quirks Mode`. Are they relevant?

Comment: Wait, I think I've found a solution. I was opening the link on Brave, but now that I tried it on Chrome, it worked (facepalm). I thought Brave and Chrome would yield the same result since both are based on the Chrome engine, but it doesn't seem to be the case. At any rate, it would be nice if you guys added a more helpful error message, and a paragraph about this in the documentation. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why or how, but **opening the link through Chrome (or another browser?)** actually worked. I was opening it through Brave, thinking that, since both are based on the Chrome engine, nothing would change.

Answer (score 1):

This might be happening due to some extension.

Try using the incognito mode or private tab (without extensions). I was using Firefox and I get this error. But it worked when I tried in a Private tab.